# Report of Pages Author (Publisher) name

Tags: silverstripe

I'm working on a large scale content-base website
in this website many Users produce content in many type of pages, and i want to know how many users(author) create how many page and produce content (for example in this month)
(no difference on reports or front-end)
is there any add-on?

Comment: Hi Misgah. What have you tried so far? Can you share your code please?

Comment: @Misgah90, StackOverflow is for helping you when you get stuck, not for creating a solution for you. Please take some time and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're happy to help you when you show us what you've tried so far and where you have problems.

Comment: i correct my question

Answer (score 1):

There is no addon for this.  First you have to define what "create how many page" and "produce content".. is this the the act of adding a page? or publishing the page?  it editing the page at all producing content?

There is a "core" report in the cms module named [Recently Edited](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/master/code/Reports/RecentlyEditedReport.php).  You can examine this to determine how reports work.  Then you will need to add various [extension "hooks"](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/) to track the operations required...

- onBeforeWrite
- onAfterWrite
- onBeforePublish
- onAfterPublish

Within these methods you will probably need to log the data you wish to report on along with Member::currentUserID() and remember while in an extenstion to access the object you need to use $this->owner->FieldName (instead of ($this->FieldName).